# how to make floating window launcher on android device?

Tags: android, window, launcher, floating

Does anyone have any idea how this can be implemented?
Some examples:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oryon.multitasking

I do not know the starting point to develop such app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point could be for example looking into the [StandOut library](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut).

Comment: Your answer will be helpful of me. Thanks

Comment: If it helped you, be sure to accept the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work